# Builder Pattern Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, design-patterns, nullpointerexception, builder

I get Null Pointer Exception when running the code below:

```java
public class Engine{

    private String name = null;
    private Mercedes m = null;

    private Engine() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Mercedes getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(Mercedes m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public static EngineBuilder builder() {
        return new EngineBuilder();
    }

    public static class EngineBuilder {
        private Engine e = null;

        public EngineBuilder builder() {
            e = new Engine();
            return this;
        }

        public Engine build() {
            return this.e;
        }

        public EngineBuilder setName(String name) {
            this.e.setName(name);
            return this;
        }

        public EngineBuilder setM(Mercedes m) {
            this.e.setM(m);
            return this;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EngineBuilder builder = Engine.builder();
        builder.setName("test");
                
        Engine e = builder.build();

    }
}
}
```

I expected the Builder pattern would work, but I got

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Engine.setName(String)" because "this.e" is null"

Comment: The exception clearly states what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your code EngineBuilder class have only default constructor, Which does not initialize Engine Object. Write a constructor which initializes required objects.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `Engine e` in `EngineBuilder` is initialized only in its `builder()` method which is never called. There's multiple ways to fix your code although I'd implement the builder pattern in a different way:

```java
public class Engine {

  private final String name;

  private Engine(Builder builder) {
    this.name = builder.name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }

  public static class Builder {

    private String name;

    private Builder() {
    }

    public Builder name(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    public Engine build() {
      return new Engine(this);
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Engine mercedes = Engine.builder().name("Mercedes").build();

    System.out.println(mercedes);  // Mercedes
  }

}
```

If you want the instances of the `Engine` class to act as traditional POJOs then remove `final` from its attributes and add a `public` default constructor and setters to it.

Answer (score 0):

you need add constructor in builder.

```java
public class Engine{

    private String name = null;
    private Mercedes m = null;

    private Engine() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Mercedes getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(Mercedes m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public static EngineBuilder builder() {
        return new EngineBuilder();
    }

    public static class EngineBuilder {
        private Engine e = null;
        // you need add Constructor in Builder
        public EngineBuilder(){
            e = new Engine();
        }

        public EngineBuilder builder() {
            e = new Engine();
            return this;
        }

        public Engine build() {
            return this.e;
        }

        public EngineBuilder setName(String name) {
            this.e.setName(name);
            return this;
        }

        public EngineBuilder setM(Mercedes m) {
            this.e.setM(m);
            return this;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EngineBuilder builder = Engine.builder();
        builder.setName("test");
                
        Engine e = builder.build();

    }
}
```